# How do I empty the memory pool?

Tags: bitcoind

I have some transactions pending in the memory pool, how do I empty the memory pool without restarting bitcoind ?
I would like the transactions to be cancelled also.

Comment: I think with bitcoind this is not possible. Are you referring to transactions to/from your wallet? Or do you mean any transaction?

Comment: Transactions cannot be cancelled. The best you can try is to double-spend them and hope that miners will ignore both transactions because you are double-spending. (I don't know what the policies for double-spending are at the largest miners.)

Comment: I have rolled back the question at @drcelus' request, who felt that the edit fundamentally changed the question. drcelus: You could have reverted it yourself by going to the edit-history and clicking "rollback" on your version's header.

Comment: @StevenRoose Your comment looks much like a decent start for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has the transaction already been mined into a block? I'm assuming not since it's in your raw mem pool. Why wasn't it mind in that case? Did it not have any fee?

I would try sending the coins to yourself with a much larger fee than the original transaction. Like Steven Roose said above, once transactions have been sent out to the network, they can't really be undone. **Even if you delete it from your raw mem pool, it's still in everyone elses raw mem pool just waiting to be confirmed.**

To make your own custom transaction that spends the UTXOs you want to spend, use the rpc calls:

```
listtransactions
listunspent
createrawtransaction
signrawtransaction
```

The default behaviour is for clients to accept whatever transactions spend an UTXO first. So most standard clients will not accept secondary spends of specific UTXOs. Mining pools may be a little bit more persuadable.

Not sure how viable this is, but I just found this: http://www.bitundo.com/. Read up on it before giving any money to a service like this. It also only works for transactions that haven't been confirmed into blocks at all yet.

I would also read this article http://bitcoinmagazine.com/2960/instant-transaction-fraud-an-explanation/. It has some very interesting stuff relevant to this question.